# Using recursion to iterate instead of FOR loops

Tags: javascript

I recently starting using eslint with the Airbnb rules. It got super angry at the following code that used `for` loops. I couldn't just ignore the rule and decided try and write the iteration logic using recursion.

The code that follows the original is my solution. I am wondering if this is correct or if there is a better way to handle this situation. Here is the rule I was trying to fix: https://github.com/airbnb/javascript/blob/master/README.md#iterators-and-generators.

I need to `await` the Neo4j queries as I iterate through.

**ORIGINAL**

```
for (const row of allArgsInUseReduce) { // eslint-disable-line
  for (const key in row) { // eslint-disable-line
    const cypher = allUtilReducers.generateCypher('CYPHER_GET_PROPERTY', key, row[key])
    const neo4jPropInUse = await allNeo4j.tx(allNeo4jTx, 'NO OBJECT', cypher) // eslint-disable-line
    for (const result of neo4jPropInUse) { // eslint-disable-line
      if (neo4jPropInUse.length !== 0) {
        const neo4jProperties = result.get('RESULT').properties
        if (neo4jProperties[thingSerialNumber] !== owner) {
          results = [...results, Object.assign({}, { key })]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**RECURSIVE**

```
let objectCounter = 0
const numObjects = allArgsInUseReduce.length
const eachObject = async function calledForEachObject() {
  const object = allArgsInUseReduce[objectCounter]
  let keyCounter = 0
  const keys = Object.keys(allArgsInUseReduce[objectCounter])
  const numKeys = keys.length
  const eachKey = async function calledForEachKey() {
    const key = keys[keyCounter]
    const value = object[key]
    const cypher = allUtilReducers.generateCypher('CYPHER_GET_PROPERTY', key, value)
    const neo4jPropInUse = await allNeo4j.tx(allNeo4jTx, 'NO OBJECT', cypher)
    neo4jPropInUse.forEach((result) => {
      if (neo4jPropInUse.length !== 0) {
        const neo4jProperties = result.get('RESULT').properties
        if (neo4jProperties[thingSerialNumber] !== owner) {
          results = [...results, key]
        }
      }
    })
    if (numKeys === (keyCounter + 1)) return
    keyCounter += 1
    await eachKey()
  }
  await eachKey()
  if (numObjects === (objectCounter + 1)) return
  objectCounter += 1
  await eachObject()
}
await eachObject()
```

Comment: You're misunderstanding a couple of things. First, your new code isn't using recursion; recursion is when a function calls itself. Second, the eslint errors weren't suggesting you use `async` and `await`methods, they were suggesting you use native iterable methods like [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach). So rather than `for (const key in row) {` you'd do `row.forEach(function(key) {`

Comment: @Hamms, I'm not sure what you mean. eachObject calls itself and so does eachKey. Also, you cannot await inside a forEach loop, which is why I went this way.

Comment: Ah, I see what you're doing now. My apologies; I was confused by the methods being named twice. If your `allNeo4j.tx` can be done in parallel, then what you probably want to do is use [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) and [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)